# Is it possible to increase the size of the commit message preview in gitkraken

Tags: gitkraken

When I want to see the commit history of a repo I like to look at the commit message. A lot of open source project add a lot of information in the commit message.

One of those repo uses markdown to write those message and with the size of the text box it means I can only see the first line of the message.

Is it possible to make the box bigger? I know I can scroll, but I pretty much have to scroll line by line and since the scroll bar is also very short it's not very precise. It makes it very hard to just read a basic commit message.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about

[image]

There's plenty of text under the first line and it's unreasonably hard to read it directly in gitkraken.

It's technically possible to click on the message which will open the reword view that can be expanded, but I just want to read the message without risking an unnecessary reword.